# How to return Loader object as Class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex4.5

I have to implement a menu with icons using actionscript only.
I create a data provider from XML and set

```
menu = Menu.createMenu(null, dataArray, true);
menu.iconFunction = iconFunction;
```

Till here everything is fine and my menu is presented, but only with labels.
I create `iconFunction` as following:

```
private function iconFunction(item:Object):Class
{
   var st:Loader = new Loader();
   st.load(new URLRequest(item.icon));
   return ?;
}
```

and here's my question: how do I return my `loader object as Class`?
I'm googling this for hours and cannot find something relevant.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Ben Stucki's solution](http://blog.benstucki.net/?p=42) as a base.

Comment: tried that - doesn't work for some reason. I don't use mxml - everything is built with actionscript. I see the image loads, but it doesn't draw in the menu.

Comment: You can't use this code without changes. Just use it as a pattern and adjust these principles for your task.

Comment: Thanks, finally I figured out how to customize this code for my needs, now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Will this example help?

```
package {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Main extends Sprite {

    private var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    public function Main() {
        urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
        urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://server.com/image.jpg"));

       urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
   }

   private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
       var loader:Loader = new Loader();
       loader.loadBytes(urlLoader.data);
       addChild(loader);
   }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. What I really need is an example on how to set icons in the menu control, while the data provider is an array of Objects?

Comment: go with http://blog.benstucki.net/?p=42, the utility loads remote assets (images) as Class'es

Comment: thanks, seems to be promising, but it didn't work for menu items. May be it works for buttons and so on, but not menu items. Do you have an example of mx:menu, that is created in actionscript and uses icons? But loads them dynamically?